# Fancytree - Multiple Trees ID Generation

Tags: fancytree

I am trying to use multiple trees on a single page/view.
I need the node ID's generated and numbered individually per tree.

When generating, the other trees continue generating ID # by incrementing the last number used in the previous tree. What I want is to have them all re-number starting from 1 again.

I saw that `initID` was commented out in a demo.
I tried to use `initID` but could not figure it out. I cannot find any documentation on it either.
Is `initID` still available? If so, how do I use it? How else would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate those keys on the server and add them to the data, or implement the `defaultKey` callback option client-side in Javascript.

Note that if you enable `generateIds: true`, this will lead to duplicate HTML IDs, which is not allowed. So in this case you have to choose different values for the `idPrefix` option.